# optimize apache for just one client

Tags: apache-2.2, optimization

So I set up apache2 to serve web service. The only consumer of it (and the whole server) will be .net web application. Firstly, is it correct to assume that this way apache will only see one client?
If it is correct then how do I optimize it in this light? Specifically, would it be correct to do something like:

```
MaxKeepAliveRequests 0  #instead of MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

KeepAliveTimeout 300 #instead of KeepAliveTimeout 15
```

Comment: Which MPM are you using?

Comment: @Shane Madden Not sure what mpm is, but `apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES` lists `mpm_prefork_module (static)` and apache2.conf has `<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
StartServers       1
MinSpareServers    1
MaxSpareServers    5
MaxClients        10
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like it's already been specifically configured for a small number of clients.

`StartServers 1` means that it's not going to over-allocate resources for more clients than it's going to get, and `MaxClients 10` is way lower than you'd see a default config.  Extra hot servers that aren't needed would be the main concern for resource usage for a low client count server - but, even then, it's not like idle servers are a large resource drain.

The keep-alive settings that you're looking at altering are unlikely to make a difference - depends on the behavior of the client application, but, more likely it's going to terminate connections after completing requests for all resources on a page, instead of leaving a connection open expecting more requests.  However, the changes certainly won't hurt.